# How to use mapply to calculate CCF for list of pairs of time series?

Tags: r, time-series, mapply

I am trying to apply functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369109/finding-lag-at-which-cross-correlation-is-maximum-ccf) for a set of time series. For this, mapply seems to be a good approach but I guess there is some problem either in defining the function or in using mapply.

Here is the example code, where I found some discrepancy in the format of dataframe being returned and might be the source of error.

```
# define the function to apply

ccffunction <- function(x, y, plot = FALSE){
    ts1 = get(x)
    ts2 = get(y)
    d <- ccf(ts1, ts2,lag.max = 24, plot = plot)
    cor = d$acf[,,1]
    lag = d$lag[,,1]
    dd <- data.frame(lag = lag, ccf = cor)
    return(t(dd)) # if I dont take transpose, not getting a df but info on the contents. 

# It seems that mapply is adding the results from two series vertically ; 
# and main part may be to define correct format of object returned
}

# List of time series simulated for testing results 

rm(list = ls())
set.seed(123)

ts1 = arima.sim(model = list(ar=c(0.2, 0.4)), n = 10)
ts2 = arima.sim(model = list(ar=c(0.1, 0.2)), n = 10)
ts3 = arima.sim(model = list(ar=c(0.1, 0.8)), n = 10)

assign("series1", ts1)
assign("series2" , ts2)
assign("series3" , ts3)

tslist <- list(series1 = ts1, series2 = ts2, series3 = ts3)


# convert to mts object if it makes any difference 

tsmts <- do.call(cbind, tslist)

class(tsmts)


# create pairs of time series using combn function

tspairs <- combn(names(tslist), 2)
tspairs


tspairs2 <- combn(colnames(tsmts), 2)
tspairs2



try1 <- mapply(ccffunction, tspairs[1, ], tspairs[2, ])


try2 <- mapply(function(x, y){ccf(x, y)}, tspairs2[1, ], tspairs2[2,])
```

I expected try2 to work directly when pairs of time series are created as combn(tslist, 2) and using plyr::mlply to input time series as arguments but that approach does not work or not using correctly.

Is there a way to find CCF matrix for a set of time series using this approach or any alternatives ?

Edits : Tried to make the question more clear and specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ccff <- function(tsVec)
{
   return (list(ccf(tsVec[[1]], tsVec[[2]], plot=FALSE)))
}

corList <- aaply(combn(tslist, 2), 2, ccff)
```

The results are stored in `corList` which can then accessed through `corList[[1]]`.

KeyPoints:

- Note the `tsVec[[1]]` in the function definition. `ccff` essentially receives a list, hence the `[[]]`.
- Also note the `return (list(...))` in the function definition. That is needed to be able to merge all the return values from the function into a single data structure from the caller.

Hope this helps.

Thank you,

GK

http://gk.palem.in/

Comment: +1 Thank you for the reply. Is that the reason mapply function above doesnt work ? I am just curious to know what I missed there and maybe  that works for getting the pair names. How can I get the pair names with aaply ?

Comment: `mapply` is similar to `sapply` and I do not think really fits your purpose here. Pairs of names with aaply is pretty straight forward, which was already indicated in the answer to earlier question. Here it is for your reference: `corList <- aaply(combn(names(tslist), 2), 2, function(x) paste(x[1], '-', x[2]))
`

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of some one liner with aaply itself. Like lapply on names or using sapply when it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

ccf cannot get the time-series object - which is what the `get` in `try1` does.

So, in `try2` you are simply passing `ccf` two strings, because it cannot see the time-series objects.

`> ccf("a_string","another_string")
Error in acf(X, lag.max = lag.max, plot = FALSE, type = type, na.action = na.action) : 
  'x' must be numeric`

and
`mapply(function(x, y){ccf(x, y)}, tspairs2[1, ], tspairs2[2,])
Error in acf(X, lag.max = lag.max, plot = FALSE, type = type, na.action = na.action) : 
  'x' must be numeric`

Comment: I know and that is why ccffunction is defined to get the series back from the strings. I first tried using combn function directly as combn(tslist, 2) and not on names. I mentioned that because there were examples using combn and mlply functions in which functions can be applied directly and want to know if that its possible to apply ccf directly on the ts list in some way.